# ArcGIS Datastore ./changebackuplocation

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to change the datastore backup location to our storage server but i get an error saying "There is a database backup process running"

A bit of context: I just restarted the machine and tried to change it's location but i got this error. I do not have a schedule for backups set.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked into it a bit more and i found the solution.

Using the command ./listbackups you can see any ongoing backups, there may be leftover failed backups that did not stop even though they encountered an error.

After that you can use the command "deletebackup" to stop the process.

Hope other people will find this usefull and not waste too much time.

[image]